# .net cross-application configuration settings

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, configuration-files

How would I share configuration data between .net desktop apps? I have used a common .ini file before but now when transitioning into .net I wonder if that's the preferred way any longer? App.config seems more like an application specific file more than a common config file and I don't know how to write settings there as ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set(...) seems not to actually write any changes.

Comment: You can also use *machine.config* for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to redirect configuration section to an external file via configSource attribute,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx

So you can put common settings in such a file, and load it in several app.config files.

Comment: What is the scope of the redirected file? must it be in or under the .exe's folder or can it be aynywhere in the file system?

Comment: Not sure if this will work. I'm fairly sure (at least in a web context) that the config source has to be in the same "~" application direcotry.

Comment: It's not just locating the file, user doing it will need at least read write permissions. Medium size tin of worms this. Sneaky Pete suggests, having the user / create / locate the config file. Can't find or don't bother a reasonable set of defaults. That way you can leave all teh admin stuff, upto them, they could even put it on share if they wanted.

Comment: Again I run into the problem of persisting changes. If I reference an external .config file, then load it with ConfigurationManager.getSection(...) how would I be able to make changes to the configuration settings? Perhaps my question was unclear here, sorry. I do want to write the settings at runtime.

Comment: ConfigurationManager.GetSection never gives you a chance to write any settings, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection.aspx.